# How can I group two list in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

I have two list in one object.

Here is json data:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "groupId": 6,
            "priority": 1,
            "groupParentId": null
        }
    ],
    "services": [
        {
            "serviceId": 6,
            "price": 100,
            "timestamp": "2020-03-09T09:04:28",
            "groupId": 6,
            "priority": 1,
            "loyaltyLevel": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to group groups and services array by groupId. In output I want to receive `List<Group, List<Service>>`

Comment: I'm which context do you need rx? This could be done with a simple method and probably you can just put it inside a map in an Rx chain

Comment: I know how I can group if it is one list. Here example https://gist.github.com/artzmb/26972459cd97373087cedb937da4f631
But I don't know how I can group if it is two list and need to group dependency first list.